# adding images to letter

Tags: graphics, letters

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Thin Formal Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 2.0 (7/2/17)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Author:
% Vel (vel@LaTeXTemplates.com)
%
% Originally based on an example on WikiBooks 
% (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Letters) but rewritten as of v2.0
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[10pt]{letter} % 10pt font size default, 11pt and 12pt are also possible

\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions

%\longindentation=0pt % Un-commenting this line will push the closing "Sincerely," to the left of the page
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    top=2cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
    left=4cm, % Left margin
    right=3cm, % Right margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters

\usepackage{stix} % Use the Stix font by default

\usepackage{microtype} % Improve justification




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   YOUR NAME & ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\signature{\textbf{Gurdeep Kaur Bibra}} % Your name for the signature at the bottom

\address{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{images/ashoka.png} \\ \textbf{Mrs. (Dr.) Gurdeep Kaur Bibra}\\B-307 Jasmine Court \\ Poonamallee High Road \\ Kattupakkam \\ Chennai--600 056 \\ Ph. 89640 44400\\email-- {jsbibra@gmail.com}} % Your address and phone number

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ADDRESSEE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{\textbf{The Branch Manager} \\ State Bank of India (00615) \\ Main Branch, Civil Lines\\Near Katchery  \\ Bareilly -- 243001 \\ Uttar Pradesh\\email--sbi.00615@sbi.co.in\\IFSC--SBIN00000615\\MICR--243002002\\Ph--0581--2423342, 2471173, 2425439} % Name/title of the addressee

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LETTER CONTENT SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\opening{\textbf{Dear Sir,}}

It is submitted that I am holding a Pension Account in your Branch with the following details\\
\\
Saving Bank Account No  10897690837\\
CIF No                  80730904206\\
\\
I also have four Fixed Deposits(FDs) with your Branch with following details\\
\\
Account No 35500431950\\
Account No 33824195283\\
Account No 33824196672\\
Account No 33824198182\\
\\
A photostat copy of the FDs is also enclosed\\
It is requested to transfer the above mentioned fixed deposits(FDs) to my account at SBI, Chennai at the earliest, since I am unable to travel to Bareilly, due to my advanced age of 92 years, and, fracture in the back\\ 
\\
The details of my account at SBI, Chennai are as under\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
Thank you for your co-operation.

%I look forward to your reply.

\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics
\closing{Sincerely,}
\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics

%\ps{P.S. You can find additional information attached to this letter.} % Postscript text, comment this line to remove it

\encl{Fixed Deposit details } % Enclosures with the letter, comment this line to remove it

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

how do i shift the logo to the left
and give a vertical line on the left side of the sender address\

how to send the date down below the recepient address[image]

Completed the date part sending it downwards with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\opening}[1]{\ifx\@empty\fromaddress
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}%
    %{\raggedleft\@date\par}%       <--- REMOVED
  \else  % home address
    \thispagestyle{empty}%
    {\raggedleft\begin{tabular}{l@{}}\ignorespaces
      %\fromaddress \\*[2\parskip]% <--- REMOVED
      %\@date \end{tabular}\par}%   <--- REMOVED
      \fromaddress%                 <--- ADDED
      \end{tabular}\par}%           <--- ADDED
  \fi
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  {\raggedright \toname \\ \toaddress \par}%
  { \hspace{9cm} \@date\par}%          <--- ADDED
  \vspace{2\parskip}%
  #1\par\nobreak}
\makeatother
```

thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301221/197451

[image]

gotit thaks to @bernard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this, based on `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{letter} % 10pt font size default, 11pt and 12pt are also possible

\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions

%\longindentation=0pt % Un-commenting this line will push the closing "Sincerely," to the left of the page
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    top=2cm, % Top margin
    bottom=2cm, % Bottom margin
    left=4cm, % Left margin
    right=3cm, % Right margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{stix} % Use the Stix font by default

\usepackage{microtype} % Improve justification




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% YOUR NAME & ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\signature{\textbf{Gurdeep Kaur Bibra}} % Your name for the signature at the bottom

\address{\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X!{\color{IndianRed}\vrule width1.5pt\,}l@{}}\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height + 3ex}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[scale=.1]{images/ashoka.png}} & \textbf{Mrs. (Dr.) Gurdeep Kaur Bibra}\\ & B-307 Jasmine Court \\ & Poonamallee High Road \\ & Kattupakkam \\ & Chennai--600 056 \\ & Ph. 89640 44400\\ & email-- {jsbibra@gmail.com}\end{tabularx}} %
% Your address and phone number

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% ADDRESSEE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{letter}{\textbf{The Branch Manager} \\ State Bank of India (00615) \\ Main Branch, Civil Lines\\Near Katchery \\ Bareilly -- 243001 \\ Uttar Pradesh\\email--sbi.00615@sbi.co.in\\IFSC--SBIN00000615\\MICR--243002002\\Ph--0581--2423342, 2471173, 2425439} % Name/title of the addressee

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% LETTER CONTENT SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\opening{\textbf{Dear Sir,}}

It is submitted that I am holding a Pension Account in your Branch with the following details\\
\\
Saving Bank Account No 10897690837\\
CIF No 80730904206\\
\\
I also have four Fixed Deposits(FDs) with your Branch with following details\\
\\
Account No 35500431950\\
Account No 33824195283\\
Account No 33824196672\\
Account No 33824198182\\
\\
A photostat copy of the FDs is also enclosed\\
It is requested to transfer the above mentioned fixed deposits(FDs) to my account at SBI, Chennai at the earliest, since I am unable to travel to Bareilly, due to my advanced age of 92 years, and, fracture in the back\\
\\
The details of my account at SBI, Chennai are as under\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
Thank you for your co-operation.

%I look forward to your reply.

\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics
\closing{Sincerely,}
\vspace{2\parskip} % Extra whitespace for aesthetics

%\ps{P.S. You can find additional information attached to this letter.} % Postscript text, comment this line to remove it

\encl{Fixed Deposit details } % Enclosures with the letter, comment this line to remove it    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why only black box instead of the image

Comment: It's just because I don't have you image, so I used  the `[demo]` option for `graphicx`.  In the actual document, you only have to remove the option.